# Regular expressions: fetch certain xml attributes from a specific xml element

Tags: php, regex, xml

I have a document with the following format:

```
<scheme attr1="lorem" attr2="ipsum" global-test="text goes here" global-attr2="second text goes here">
</scheme>
```

I want to use a regular expression to extract all the attributes that match `global-(.*)`.
It can also only match on the "scheme" element, so using a simple regular expression like `(global-([^=]*)="([^"]*)")+` is not an option. I tried the following regular expression:

```
<scheme.*([\s]+global-([^=]*)="([^"]*)")+
```

But this will only match on "global-attr2", and will see the other global attributes as part of the .* selector. Making the * selector on .* lazy also doesn't seem to help.

And I know that getting data from an XML document with regular expressions isn't a good practice, but this script is for a preprocessor. It modifies the XML before parsing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) will match everything and store everything as well. So first match against "<scheme", and if it matches, then run `preg_match_all` Match against something like

```
/global-(.*?)=(\w+)/
```

and then extract from `matches[0]`, `matches[1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the (...)+ construct does not work as you expect it. It will clobber your previous matches and only save the last one, instead of extending the match group array.

Try matching something against (.)* and see if it's true for your php setup.

I tried

```
<scheme(.*?[\s]+global-([^=]*)="([^"]*)")+
```

which I believe should work if (...)+ behaved differently.